# Cannot use any CSS with a dash in the name for inline CSS in React (parser error)

Tags: reactjs

How can one use inline CSS with a dash in the name of the property in React?

My parser throws the following error when I do:

> TS1005: `The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.`

For example:

```html
<div style={{background-color:blue}}/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually inline CSS in React does not include the dash. So `background-color` would be `backgroundColor`.

See e.g. *[Styling React Using CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)*.